# Displaying continuous chats from a user in a same bubble

Tags: android, android-listview, whatsapp

I am working on chat app.. 
This is what I have done till now. 
[image: chat bw two]

Now what I want is this:
[image: grouping continuous chat from a user]

Please I am stuck and getting no idea how to work upon this UI.. 
i.e
If a user view views the chat again,then if msg were continuous from a user,then show them in the same bubble as in second image.
This chat thing is all local,no services or server used.
I am giving my code.

MessageActivity.java

```
public class MessageActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

ArrayList<Message> messages;
AwesomeAdapter adapter;
EditText text;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    text = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.text);


    this.setTitle("Harish");
    messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    adapter = new AwesomeAdapter(this, messages);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
public void sendMessage(View v)
{
    String newMessage = text.getText().toString().trim(); 
    //String msg="\nTesting";
    if(newMessage.length() > 0)
    {
        text.setText("");
        //addNewMessage(new Message(newMessage+msg, true));
        addNewMessage(new Message(newMessage, true));
    }
}
public void sendMessage2(View v)
{
    String newMessage = text.getText().toString().trim(); 
    if(newMessage.length() > 0)
    {
        text.setText("");
        addNewMessage(new Message(newMessage, false));

    }
}
void addNewMessage(Message m)
{
    messages.add(m);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    getListView().setSelection(messages.size()-1);
}
```

}

AwesomeAdapter.java

```
public class AwesomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Message> mMessages;



public AwesomeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> messages) {
    super();
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mMessages = messages;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mMessages.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {       
    return mMessages.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Message message = (Message) this.getItem(position);

    ViewHolder holder; 
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.sms_row, parent, false);
        holder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.message.setText(message.getMessage());

    LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) holder.message.getLayoutParams();


        if(message.isMine())
        {
            holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.me);
            lp.setMargins(15, 10, 0, 10);


        }

        else
        {
            holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.you);
            lp.setMargins(0, 10, 15, 10);
        }
        holder.message.setLayoutParams(lp);


    return convertView;
}
private static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView message;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

Message.java

```
public class Message {

String message;

boolean isMine;

public Message(String message, boolean isMine) {
    super();
    this.message = message;
    this.isMine = isMine;

}
/**
 * Constructor to make a status Message object
 * consider the parameters are swaped from default Message constructor,
 *  not a good approach but have to go with it.
 */
public Message(boolean status, String message) {
    super();
    this.message = message;
    this.isMine = false;

}
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public boolean isMine() {
    return isMine;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On getting a new message, append that message to the previous message in the `ArrayList<Message>`(i.e. get previous message from the arraylist and add append this new message with a line break(`\n`) and it should work) and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: how to draw that horizontal line ?

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that, You have to handle it in your getView(). Create row item programmatically instead of inflating an XML layout. Adding a 1dp view with a color background draws a line.

Comment: I am a beginner,can u explain more or  give some example related to this,I will learn from there.

Comment: So you have to redesign your Message. Make it array of Messages or arraylist of messages. So you can create as many as textviews as you can with a divider seperating them.

Comment: go through this to learn how to create view programmatically: http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/220-lesson-16-creating-layout-programmatically-layoutparams.html

Comment: Seshu I was able to do the half part of this ie. showing chats from a user together. I used StringBuilder to append the msgs togethr based on conditions and then called addNewMessage().



Now I am still stuck with how to show horizontal line b/w those appended String msgs. plz help

Comment: You shouldn't be using XML layout to inflate a list row.

Comment: You have to create it using java code. Go through the above link to create view programmatically